# Relaciones para una sistema de calificaciones en una escuela primaria MySQL WorkBench

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Todavía tengo algunas dudas de crear el siguiente modelo relacional, en esta base de datos es para una escuela primaria, donde se necesita guardar las calificaciones de los alumnos donde se califican por bimestre teniendo el curso 5 bimestres, se necesita guardar cada calificación de cada alumno por bimestre y por asignatura. En mi lógica he hecho una relación de muchos a muchos con calificación y alumno, sin embargo no se si este bien:
[image: Modelo relacional de la base de datos]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque el modelado admita varias soluciones, en este caso está claro que te sobra la tabla `Alumno_has_Calificacion`, porque la relación entre las dos entidades `Alumno` y `Asignatura` es precisamente la `Calificacion` que ya has creado.

Si la llamas `Califican`, lo verás un poco más claro porque se corresponderá mejor con el modelo conceptual/ER de Chen, en el que se recomienda usar nombres para las entidades y verbos para las relaciones, aunque al pasarlo al modelo relacional sean todo tablas. Con añadirle a cada calificación el `idAlumno` ya tendrás tu problema resuelto.

¿Tu diseño funcionaría? Sí, funcionaría. Te quedarían las consultas un poco más complicadas y usarías una tabla para hacer el trabajo de un campo, pero funcionaría. Te recomiendo mirarte el tema de la cardinalidad para simplificar tus diseños.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Ok, entonces solamente para aclarar, la relación de muchos a muchos de `Alumno` a `Calificacion` me quedaría de sobra porque me crea la tabla `Alumno_has_Calificacion`. Entonces lo optimo seria hacer una relación de 1 a muchos con 'Alumno' a 'Calificacion' ?

Comment: Sí, eso es: cada calificación únicamente puede ser de un alumno y de una asignatura en concreto